# How to implement a discrete data representation?

Tags: programming, data-structures, object-oriented

I'm currently working with large datasets of "discrete data".  Each of these is a *multiset* of real numbers of the form $kS + B$, where $k$ is an integer, and $S$ (the *"scale*") and $B$ (the *"bias"*) are real values.

These datasets are such that it is often economical to represent them as "tallies":

```
dd = <| 
        "scale" -> 1.234,
        "bias"  -> 5.678,
        "tally" -> {{-5, 2},
                    {-4, 251},
                    {-3, 5941},
                    {-2, 60383},
                    {-1, 241185},
                    { 0, 383613},
                    { 1, 241644},
                    { 2, 61035},
                    { 3, 5686},
                    { 4, 259},
                    { 5, 1}}
     |>
```

The `"scale"` and `"bias"` entries are $S$ and $B$, as described already.  The `"tally"` entry is a list of pairs $\{k, n\}$, where $n$ is the number of times that $kS + B$ appears in the data.

(The example above is just a toy; in practice, the `"tally"` elements are much longer, but still far more compact than the simple `List` representation of the data.)

One can recover the fully expanded representation from the tally representation with the function

```
(#[["bias"]] + #[["scale"]] Flatten[ ConstantArray @@@ #[["tally"]] ]) &
```

---

Even though the tally representation is not a sparse array, it would be nice to give it an interface similar to that of a `SparseArray` object.

The most important feature of such an interface is *the ability to behave correctly in any **context** where normally a list would be expected.*

For example, it would be nice if `Length[dd]` automatically behaved like `Plus @@ (Last /@ dd[["tally"]])` when given a discrete data object `dd` as argument.

And more generally, if a list is expected, and no special method is available (like the one for `Length` above), the discrete data object would be automatically expanded to its full list form.

How does one do this in *Mathematica*?

---

Python, for one, solves this problem by specifying a set of standard methods that will get called on an object when it is in one of a corresponding set of contexts.  For example, if for some Python object `x` the method `__length__` exists, then the value of the expression `len(x)` will evaluate to whatever `x.__length__()` returns.  In contexts where `x` is expected to be iterated over, `x.__iterator__` will be invoked.  Etc.

Therefore, by implementing a few standard methods (like `__length__` and `__iterator__`), one can define new classes that can be used like the standard classes (lists, dicts, etc) even if they have completely different internal implementations.

Is there something like this in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Making discrete Data an abstract data type

I would try to do something like the following:

```
(* write a constructor function for the data type 'discrete data' *)
discreteData[ 
      scale_?NumericQ , 
      bias_?NumericQ , 
      tally : { { _?NumericQ , _?NumericQ } .. }
   ] := discreteData @ Association[
   "scale" -> scale,
   "bias" -> bias,
   "tally" -> tally
]

(* define upvalues *)
discreteData /: Length[ d_discreteData ] := With[
    { assoc = d[[1]] },
    Plus @@ ( Last /@ assoc[["tally"]] )
]

discreteData /: Normal[ d_discreteData ] := With[
    { assoc = d[[1]] },
    assoc[["bias"]] + assoc[[ "scale" ]] Flatten [  
        ConstantArray @@@ assoc[["tally"]] 
    ]
]

(* If you prefer, you can make Dataset the printed form of this data type *)
discreteData/: Format[ d_discreteData ] := With[
    { assoc = d[[1]] },
    Dataset @ assoc
]
```

### Working with `discreteData`

Then this will work out as follows: We can construct `disctreteData` using the constructor function.

```
data = discreteData[ 
    1.234 , (* scale *)
    5.678 , (* bias *)
    { {-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, 
      {-1, 241185}, {0, 383613}, {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, 
      {4,259}, {5, 1} } (* tally *) 
]
```

[image: Dataset]

While `discreteData` are displayed as a Dataset, they internally are simply an association given an expressive `Head`:

```
InputForm @ data
```

> discreteData[<|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, 
>     "tally" -> {{-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, {-1, 241185}, {0, 383613}, 
>       {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, {4, 259}, {5, 1}}|>]

We can extract information comfortably using *Mathematica's* built-in functions (e.g. [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html), [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html)).

```
Length @ data
```

> 1 000 000

```
Normal @ data
```

> {-0.492, -0.492, 0.742, 0.742, 0.742,...,10.614, 10.614, 10.614, 10.614, 11.848}

Comment: That way it nicely blends in imo. I personally only use `Dataset` when I want a pretty output, but stick to `Association` and `List` of those for the regular work and duty.

Comment: I like the upvalue idea a lot.  One concern I have is what happens when a function for which no suitable upvalue has been defined gets applied to a `discreteData` object.  I'm particularly concerned about *silent errors*.  Consider, for example, the expression `Sqrt /@ dd`, where `dd` is a `discreteData` object as defined in your post.  This expression evaluates without error, but produces an incorrect result.  Of course, I can define an upvalue for `Map`, but `Map` is just one of a huge number of functions that may get reasonably be applied to a `discreteData` object.  ...

Comment: ...AFAICT, the crux of the matter is whether or not *Mathematica* has a *narrowly-defined* "list interface", the way other languages (e.g. Haskell, Python, etc.) have.  Maybe this should be the subject for another thread...

Comment: @kjo Yes, I noted this also - which is why I have not yet expanded this with nice definitions for `Plus` and `Times`. I wonder, how far one can push this though.

Answer (score 13):

### General

A late-to-the party post. To complement other answers, which already show most important ingredients for constructing data types with overloaded system functions, I'd like to show an approach that follows the same ideas a couple steps further.

While `UpValues` are the tool to use, one problem with them is the lack of control or introspection: they leave no middle ground between the functions they overload and actual implementations for a specific data type. In some cases, more control over the overloaded behavior might be beneficial.

The examples below are based on the code of a tiny framework, which has more didactic goal and is not meant to be directly production-usable. That code is at the end of this post.

### Defining an interface

#### Preliminaries

For the purposes of this example, we will define an interface `ListObject`, which should support versions of `Length`, `Normal`, `Part`, `Take`, `Drop`, `Map` and `Select`, as well as a type-testing predicate. The actual objects implementing this interface will look like

```
ListObject[objectContainer[inner-data]]
```

One observation here is that the operations one can perform on a list-like object can be broadly divided into non-terminal (resulting in an object of the same type) and terminal (resulting in anything else). I have wired this notion into the example framework.

So, assuming that code below (at the end of the post) has been executed, we define, as our first step:

```
Scan[SetTerminal, {Length, Normal}];
Scan[SetNonTerminal, {Part, Take, Drop, Map, Select}]
```

#### `ListObject` interface

We now define the interface symbol and testing predicate:

```
ClearAll[ListObject];
ListObject::notimpl = "The function `1` has not been implemented for backend `2`";
ListObject::badargs = "Function `1` received bad number and / or types of arguments: `2`";

ClearAll[ListObjectQ];
ListObjectQ[ListObject[backend_Symbol[___]]]:=True;
ListObjectQ[_]:=False;
```

The following code sets generic definitions for the interface functions:

```
Scan[
   SetGeneralDef[ListObject], 
   {ListLength, ListNormal, ListPart, ListTake, ListDrop, ListSelect}
];
Scan[SetGeneralDef[ListObject][#, 2]&, {ListMap}];
```

where new symbols starting with `List` are part of the `ListObject` interface.

Next, we define the dispatch:

```
Def[ListObject] @ Length @ ListObject -> ListLength
Def[ListObject] @ Normal @ ListObject -> ListNormal
(* Force terminal behavior on Part[lst, _Integer] *)
Def[ListObject, False] @ Part[ListObject, _Integer] -> ListPart
Def[ListObject] @ Part[ListObject, __] -> ListPart
Def[ListObject] @ Take[ListObject, __] -> ListTake
Def[ListObject] @ Drop[ListObject, __] -> ListDrop
Def[ListObject] @ Map[_, ListObject, ___] -> ListMap
Def[ListObject] @ Select[ListObject, __] -> ListSelect
```

At this point, we are done defining an interface.

#### Notes

The above uses syntactic sugar, defined in the code below. What really happens is that definitions has been generated, which you can test by executing

```
?ListObject
```

For example, here is how a definition for `Map` may look:

> ```
> Map[ff$_,ListObject[backend$_],rr$:PatternSequence[___]]^:=
>    ListObject[With[{type$=ContainerType[backend$]},
>      Postprocessor[type$,Map,ListObject][ListMap[
>         Preprocessor[type$,Map,ListObject][ff$,backend$,rr$]
>      ]]]]
> ```

These definitions connect `Map` called on `ListObject[type[contents]]` with the internal symbol `ListMap`, and also adds pre- and post-processor.

### Adding a sample implementation

As an example, let us define a list-like object that would implement certain operations in a lazy fashion (very simplistically, for the sake of this example). Basically, the list object will look like

```
MyList[data, functions]
```

where `data` is the original data (a list), and `functions` is an (initially empty) list representing a queue of functions to be executed on original data. Most interface functions will add some data transformation to that queue (rather than actually doing the computation), and when one calls `Normal`, only then all the accumulated functions in the queue get applied to data, in the order they stand in `functions` list.

#### Implementation

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[MyList];
ApplyDelayed[f_, MyList[data_List, funs_List:{}]]:=
  MyList[data, Prepend[funs, f]];
MyList /: ListNormal[MyList[data_List, funs_List:{}]]:=
  Apply[Composition, funs] @ data;
MyList /: ListLength[lst_MyList]:=Length @ ListNormal @ lst;
MyList /: ListPart[MyList[data_List, funs_List:{}], p_Integer]:= 
  Apply[Composition, funs] @ data[[p]];
MyList /: ListPart[lst_MyList, spec__]:= ApplyDelayed[Part[#, spec]&, lst];
MyList /: ListTake[lst_MyList, spec_]:= ApplyDelayed[Take[#, spec]&, lst];
MyList /: ListDrop[lst_MyList, spec_]:= ApplyDelayed[Drop[#, spec]&, lst];
MyList /: ListMap[f_, lst_MyList]:=ApplyDelayed[Map[f], lst];
MyList /: ListSelect[lst_MyList, pred_]:= ApplyDelayed[Select[pred], lst];
```

#### Examples

Here, for example, we square the list, and then select odd elements. You can see that function application simply adds operations to the queue, and everything gets evaluated only when we call `Normal`:

```
Select[Map[#^2 &, ListObject[MyList[Range[10]]]], OddQ]
Normal @ Select[Map[#^2 &, ListObject[MyList[Range[10]]]], OddQ]

(* 
   ListObject[MyList[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {Select[OddQ], Map[#1^2 &]}]]

   {1, 9, 25, 49, 81}
*)
```

A somewhat larger example:

```
Take[Drop[Select[Map[#^2 &, ListObject[MyList[Range[20]]]], OddQ], 2], 5]

(* 
   ListObject[
     MyList[
       {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
       {Take[#1, 5] &, Drop[#1, 2] &, Select[OddQ], Map[#1^2 &]}
     ]
   ]
*)
```

---

Here is one way to illustrate the work of the post-processor: the code below redefines the default (trivial) post-processor for all implemented functions for type `MyList`:

```
MyList /: Postprocessor[MyList, f_, _] := Function[Print[HoldForm[f -> #]]; #]
```

We can now execute the same code:

```
Normal @ Select[Map[#^2 &, ListObject[MyList[Range[10]]]], OddQ]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[605]:= Map->MyList[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{Map[#1^2&]}]
>
> During evaluation of In[605]:= Select->MyList[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{Select[OddQ],Map[#1^2&]}]
>
> During evaluation of In[605]:= Normal->{1,9,25,49,81}
> ```

```
(* {1, 9, 25, 49, 81} *)
```

We now remove the extra definition we added:

```
MyList /: Postprocessor[MyList, f_, _] =.
```

One can (re) define post-processors more granularly, on the level of individual functions, for example:

```
ListMap /: Postprocessor[MyList, ListMap, _]:=...
```

One can obviously do more interesting things than just printing. For example, catching some errors / exceptions, or inserting non-trivial data post-processing.

---

Let's now see what happens if we try using some types, unknown to the system:

```
Normal[ListObject[UnknownList[stuff]]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[606]:= ListObject::notimpl: The function ListNormal has not been implemented for backend UnknownList
>
> During evaluation of In[606]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[$Failed,Error[ListNormal]] returned to top level.
> ```

```
(* Hold[Throw[$Failed, Error[ListNormal]]] *)
```

This is in contrast to the usual behavior:

```
Normal[UnknownList[stuff]]

(* UnknownList[stuff] *)
```

which is much softer, but such softness isn't always good - often we actually may prefer to get an error instead of just silently returning an expression back.

### What's the difference?

One may ask how the above construct fundamentally differs from what has been already suggested. The main difference is that here, we really defined an interface rather than an abstract data type. An interface does not really provide specific implementation, rather it provides a contract that all compatible implementations should meet.

The core mechanism here is the same as before - using `UpValues`. However, the above scheme gives one more control, essentially because we go though an intermediate step: instead of doing, for example, `Map[MyList]` -> `MyList` implementation, we do `Map[ListObject[MyList]]` -> `ListMap[MyList]` -> `MyList` implementation. So, the main features of this approach are then:

- All code execution for all implemented types now goes through a single intermediate step (one of the `List...` functions).
- There are ways to intercept the computations, facilitated by pre- and post-processors.
- We can have a harder (or, generally, more customizable) default behavior in terms of error-handling and reporting.

I would not necessarily bother with such more complex construction for a single throw-away data type, but if I were planning to build an extensible framework where the users may implement new types, then having something like this may provide advantages for both myself as a framework author, and the users.

For example, should I want to change the behavior of some of the functions for all implementations of `ListObject`, all I have to do is to change the definition of the mapping of system symbol to interface symbol (e.g. `Map` to `ListMap`) - in the simplest case, by (re)defining pre- and / or post-processor. I would not need to touch any of the user implementations of `ListObject` interface for that.

### The code for the interface generation

#### Interface-generation micro-framework

```
ClearAll[MsgFail];
SetAttributes[MsgFail, HoldRest];
MsgFail[f_, msg_:None, args___]:= (msg; Throw[$Failed, Error[f, args]]);

ClearAll[TerminalQ, NonTerminalQ];
TerminalQ[_] = NonTerminalQ[_]=False;

(* Wraps non-terminal operations with the container head *)
ClearAll[ObjectWrapper];
ObjectWrapper[obj_Symbol, op_, flag_]:= If[TrueQ @ flag, obj, Identity];
ObjectWrapper[obj_Symbol, op_?TerminalQ]:=Identity;
ObjectWrapper[obj_Symbol, op_?NonTerminalQ]:= obj;
ObjectWrapper[___]:=MsgFail[ObjectWrapper];

ClearAll[SetTerminal, SetNonTerminal];
SetTerminal[op_, flag_:True]:=TerminalQ[op]:=flag;
SetNonTerminal[op_, flag_:True]:=NonTerminalQ[op]:=flag;

(* Helper function for code generation for functions' definitions *)
ClearAll[defWrapped];
SetAttributes[defWrapped, HoldAll];
defWrapped[obj_, {f_, flag_:None},  TagSetDelayed[s_, lhs_, rhs_]]:=
  With[{wrapper = ObjectWrapper[obj, f, If[flag === None, Sequence @@ {}, flag]]},
      TagSetDelayed[s, lhs, wrapper @ rhs]; 
  ];

ClearAll[ContainerType];
ContainerType[c_Symbol[___]]:=c;
ContainerType[_]:=Null;

ClearAll[Preprocessor, Postprocessor];
Preprocessor[type_, function_, interface_]:=##&;
Postprocessor[type_, function_, interface_]:=##&;

(* Syntactic sugar for interface function dispatch definitions *)
ClearAll[Def];
SetAttributes[Def, HoldAll];
Def[obj_, flag:True|False|None:None]:=Function[code, Def[obj, code, flag], HoldAll];
Def /: Def[obj_, f_[obj_], flag_:None] ->  impl_:= 
  defWrapped[obj,{f, flag}, obj /: f[obj[backend_]]:= With[{type = ContainerType[backend]},
      Postprocessor[type, f, obj] @ impl[Preprocessor[type, f, obj] @ backend]
  ]];
Def /: Def[obj_, f_[obj_, args__], flag_:None] ->  impl_:= 
  defWrapped[obj, {f, flag}, obj /: f[obj[backend_], p:PatternSequence[args]]:=
      With[{type = ContainerType[backend]},
          Postprocessor[type, f, obj] @ impl[Preprocessor[type, f, obj][backend, p]]
      ]
  ];
Def /: Def[obj_, f_[fst_, obj_], flag_:None] ->  impl_:=
  defWrapped[obj, {f, flag}, obj /: f[ff:fst, obj[backend_]]:= 
    With[{type = ContainerType[backend]},
        Postprocessor[type, f, obj] @ impl[Preprocessor[type, f, obj][ff, backend]]
    ]
  ];
Def /: Def[obj_, f_[fst_, obj_, rest__], flag_:None] ->  impl_:=
  defWrapped[obj, {f, flag}, obj /: f[ff:fst, obj[backend_], rr:PatternSequence[rest]]:= 
    With[{type = ContainerType[backend]},
      Postprocessor[type, f, obj] @ impl @ Preprocessor[type, f, obj][ff, backend,rr]
    ]
  ]

(* General catch-all definitions for interface functions *)
ClearAll[SetGeneralDef];
SetGeneralDef[objsym_, clear_:True][f_Symbol, pos_Integer:1]:=
  With[{n = pos - 1},
    If[TrueQ[clear], ClearAll[f]];
    f[Repeated[_, {n}], backend_Symbol[___],args___]:= 
        MsgFail[f, Message[MessageName[objsym, "notimpl"], f, backend]];
    f[args___]:=MsgFail[f, Message[MessageName[objsym,"badargs"], f, {args}]];
  ];
```

#### Code for `ListObject` interface generation in one peace, for convenience

*Execute the above code for interface generation first*.

```
Scan[SetTerminal, {Length, Normal}];
Scan[SetNonTerminal, {Part, Take, Drop, Map, Select}] 

ClearAll[ListObject];
ListObject::notimpl = "The function `1` has not been implemented for backend `2`";
ListObject::badargs = "Function `1` received bad number and / or types of arguments: `2`";

ClearAll[ListObjectQ];
ListObjectQ[ListObject[backend_Symbol[___]]]:=True;
ListObjectQ[_]:=False;

Scan[
   SetGeneralDef[ListObject], 
   {ListLength, ListNormal, ListPart, ListTake, ListDrop, ListSelect}
];
Scan[SetGeneralDef[ListObject][#, 2]&, {ListMap}];

Def[ListObject] @ Length @ ListObject -> ListLength
Def[ListObject] @ Normal @ ListObject -> ListNormal
(* Force terminal behavior on Part[lst, _Integer] *)
Def[ListObject, False] @ Part[ListObject, _Integer] -> ListPart
Def[ListObject] @ Part[ListObject, __] -> ListPart
Def[ListObject] @ Take[ListObject, __] -> ListTake
Def[ListObject] @ Drop[ListObject, __] -> ListDrop
Def[ListObject] @ Map[_, ListObject, ___] -> ListMap
Def[ListObject] @ Select[ListObject, __] -> ListSelect
```

Comment: Thanks for this post.  I'm still digesting it (it will take a while).  I tried running the example you gave, but the evaluation of the `Def` expressions (e.g. `Def[ListObject]@Length@ListObject -> ListLength`) resulted in errors like `Throw::nocatch: "Uncaught Throw[$Failed,Error[ObjectWrapper]] returned to top level. "`.  I'm not sure that I'm evaluating things in the right order.  It would be helpful to collect all the code, in the right evaluation order, at the end.  Even though this would mean some repetition of code, it would remove any uncertainty around the evaluation order.

Comment: @kjo I just re-checked on a fresh kernel, everything works just fine. Basically, you first execute the framework code (the last section of the post), and then execute code in exactly the same order as given in the post:  `Scan[SetTerminal, ...]`, then definitions of `ListObject` and `ListObjectQ`, then `Scan[SetGeneralDef[ListObject], ...]`, then the interface, then `MyList` definitions, then examples. I am on Mac OS X, M11.1 (development version) from February 2017. Didn't test on 11.0 though, yet.

Comment: @kjo Ok, also tested in 11.0 just now, works just fine. Be sure to execute all code in exactly the same order as in the post (it shouldn't matter much, but just in case), with the code from the last section in the post executed first (be sure you copy it correctly, so that no pieces have been left out). Other than that, don't know what else to suggest. If the error is still there, perhaps you could send me a notebook with all the code you are executing, via email.

Comment: Thanks!  That I had no problems this time.

Answer (score 12):

I'm just throwing a different idea in the room. Let's say you have a dataset of such structures:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, 
     "tally" -> {{-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, {-1, 
        241185}, {0, 383613}, {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, {4, 
        259}, {5, 1}}|>,
    <|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, 
     "tally" -> {{-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, {-1, 
        241185}, {0, 383613}, {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, {4, 
        259}, {5, 1}}|>,
    <|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, 
     "tally" -> {{-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, {-1, 
        241185}, {0, 383613}, {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, {4, 
        259}, {5, 1}}|>
    }];
```

Would it be sufficient if you define your functions like this:

```
length = (Plus @@ (Last /@ #"tally")) &;
recover = (#"bias" + #"scale" Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ #"tally"]) &
```

and now, you can call

```
ds[All, length]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or even

```
ds[1, recover]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]