# How to disallow the application of functions outside a white list?

Tags: programming, data-structures, object-oriented

In an [earlier post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139818/2464) I described a special kind of list (actually, a special kind of *multiset*) that can be represented more efficiently with a structure like this:

```
dd = discreteData[<|"scale" -> 1.234,
                    "bias"  -> 5.678,
                    "tally" -> {{-5, 2},
                                {-4, 251},
                                {-3, 5941},
                                {-2, 60383},
                                {-1, 241185},
                                { 0, 383613},
                                { 1, 241644},
                                { 2, 61035},
                                { 3, 5686},
                                { 4, 259},
                                { 5, 1}}|>];
```

(Basically, the values encoded by this data structure are all of the form $kS + B$, where $k$ is an integer, and $S$ and $B$ are the numbers that the data structure labels `"scale"` and `"bias"`.  The `"tally"` item is a list of pairs $\{k, n\}$, where $n$ is the number of times that the value $kS + B$ appears in the data.)

Now, let

```
dd2list[dd_] := dd[[1, "bias"]] + dd[[1, "scale"]] Flatten[ ConstantArray @@@ dd[[1, "tally"]] ];
```

Since any `discreteData` object `dd` contains the same information as the corresponding `List` object `dd2list[dd]`, it would be *great* if one could arrange matters such that `dd` and `dd2list[dd]` could be used interchangeably in *Mathematica* programs.

By defining suitable upvalues, one can have `dd` behave like `dd2list[dd]` in the specified context.  E.g.

```
discreteData /: Length[ d_discreteData ] := With[
    { assoc = d[[1]] },
    Plus @@ ( Last /@ assoc[["tally"]] )
];

Length[dd] == Length[dd2list[dd]]
(* True *)
```

Unfortunately, this one upvalue covers only a tiny fraction of the expressions one is likely to find `dd` in.  If one mistakenly replaces a list object with its `discreteData` counterpart in an expression for which no proper upvalue has been defined, the results could change dramatically (and for the worse, of course).

For example, if `dd` is defined as shown above, the evaluation of `Sqrt /@ dd` succeeds without warning, and the result even has the correct "shape" (i.e. the right head, the right fields, with values also correctly dimensioned), but it is *grossly* incorrect.

Of course, one can avoid this one error by defining a suitable upvalue for `Map`, but in order to make this data structure resistant to such silent errors *in general*, one would have to implement upvalues for a huge number of list-consuming functions.  This does not seem practical to me.

In order to make such a data structure behave like a List *safely*, one needs at least one of

1. the specification of a complete list interface;
2. a way to make it a visible error to apply to objects of the new class any function that is not included in a white-list of approved functions.

(**NB:** the white-list mentioned in 2 consists of precisely those functions for which I have defined upvalues.)

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but, AFAIK, *Mathematica* has nothing like 1.

This leaves 2.  Is there a way to implement this?

---

**Clarification**: option 2 will *not* solve the problem of making `discreteData` behave like a list in any appropriate context; it only solves the problem of silent errors.

Comment: You certainly can do the second, again, using `UpValues` but I think your whitelist will be necessarily huge. Perhaps even more than the list interface.

Comment: @MB1965: The whitelist I had in mind consists of precisely those functions for which I have defined upvalues.  It will not allow my object to behave like a true list in every possible situation, but at list it will prevent silent errors.

Comment: You'll want things like Message and Hold and HoldComplete and all these things that we don't usually think of as "functions" though, too. There are just so many of them and I think you might find the system emitting more messages that you really want to deal with.

Comment: @MB1965: I see your point.  I guess I see no way to use the upvalue idea to implement this `discreteData` objects safely.  I think the silent errors I illustrated represent to big a risk.

Comment: Might be worth implementing a blacklist instead. What sort of functions are you most concerned about? For instance it seems Listable functions are most apt to cause you trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, to the best of my knowledge, is not possible to program a custom interface that is integrated at the level of atomic objects such as a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) I think some compromise is unavoidable.

Edmund's method is the first one that came to mind, and I voted for it.  It may still be your best option.

However it is not *robust* in the manner I think you are seeking.  Consider for example:

```
expr = Hold[{1, discreteData[x, y, {z1, z2, z3}], 3}];

Apply[foo, expr, {2}]
Apply[foo, expr, {3}]
Map[foo, expr, {3}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, foo[x, y, {z1, z2, z3}], 3}]
>
> Hold[{1, discreteData[x, y, foo[z1, z2, z3]], 3}]
>
> Hold[{1, discreteData[foo[x], foo[y], foo[{z1, z2, z3}]], 3}]
> ```

I imagine that none of these are the result you would *hope* to see from each operation.

Perhaps it would be better for these functions to *ignore* your construct rather than mutating it errantly.

---

## Proposal

One *compromise* to achieve this is to make a separate definition for each Symbol to which a data set is assigned.

- To do this I shall use a public function `setDiscreteData` and a global variable `$DD`
- All your UpSets should be given in the body of `setDiscreteData`

```
Attributes[setDiscreteData] = HoldFirst;

setDiscreteData[s_Symbol, rhs_] := With[{a := $DD[s]},

    a = rhs;

    s=. ^:= (ClearAll[s]; a=.);

    Set[s, new_] ^:= a = new;

    Length[s]    ^:= a // Query["tally", Tr, Last];

  ]
```

Now you would define a data set like this:

```
setDiscreteData[dd,
 <|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, 
  "tally" -> {{-5, 2}, {-4, 251}, {-3, 5941}, {-2, 60383}, {-1, 241185}, {0, 
     383613}, {1, 241644}, {2, 61035}, {3, 5686}, {4, 259}, {5, 1}}|>
];
```

The defined rules apply:

```
Length[dd]
```

> ```
> 1000000
> ```

Every other operation sees `dd` as an atomic Symbol and handles it as such:

```
expr = Hold[{1, dd, 3}];

Apply[foo, expr, {2}]
Apply[foo, expr, {3}]
Map[foo, expr, {3}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, dd, 3}]
>
> Hold[{1, dd, 3}]
>
> Hold[{1, dd, 3}]
> ```

```
Replace[dd, x_ :> foo, 1]

dd + 8
```

> ```
> dd
>
> 8 + dd
> ```

Once a data set Symbol (`dd`) has been assigned it can be reassigned with `Set`:

```
dd = 
  <|"scale" -> 1.234, "bias" -> 5.678, "tally" -> {{-1, 2}, {0, 7}, {1, 4}}|>;

Length[dd]
```

> ```
> 13
> ```

The Symbol may be reset to normal (all definitions cleared) using [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html):

```
dd=.
```

---

This method is incidentally related to [How to Set parts of indexed lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7214/121#7273)

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the role of `$DD`.  May you explain.  Also, how are you able to reassign `a` in the `With`?  I thought that the `With` variables are replaced in the body so this was not possible.  Both `With[{a = 1}, a = 2]` and `With[{a := 1}, a = 2]` produce error *Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.* for 11.0.1 on Windows.  May you explain this as well.

Comment: @Edmund `$DD` is my `DownValues` look-up table.  Every data set assignment will be made as e.g. `$DD[foo] = . . .` .  I am using an undocumented but longstanding syntax for `With`; please see [(121173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/121).  Your example is not quite the same; try instead: `x = 1; With[{a := x}, a = 2]; x`

Comment: @Edmund Did I write that in an understandable way or should I try again?

Comment: It completely understandable. Thanks.

Comment: Something like ``dd:discreteData[_Association]?System`Private`HoldEntryQ := 
 System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry@dd`` could give similar result. It wouldn't work when `discreteData` would be used directly inside held expression, but `SparseArray` also needs to *evaluate* to its atomic form.

Comment: @jkuczm I am not familiar with these functions!  Would you please add them to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121 ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [Done](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139974/14303).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample implementation of 2 although I think simply writing a generalizable list-like interface is probably the safer route:

```
whitelisted =
  Association@
   Thread[
    Thread@
      Hold@
       {
        Hold, HoldPattern, Print
        } ->
     Null];

discreteData::unknown = 
  "Result of applying function `` to discreteData object is unknown";
discreteData /:
 HoldPattern[
  func_?(Function[Null, ! KeyMemberQ[whitelisted, Hold[#]], 
      HoldAllComplete])[d_discreteData]
  ] :=
 (
  Message[discreteData::unknown, HoldForm[func]];
  d
  );
discreteData /:
  HoldPattern[
   func_?(Function[Null, ! KeyMemberQ[whitelisted, Hold[#]], 
       HoldAllComplete])[a___, d_discreteData, b___]
   ] :=
  (
   Message[discreteData::unknown, HoldForm[func]];
   HoldComplete[func[a, d, b]]
   );
```

Then:

```
In[727]:= List[discreteData[1]]

During evaluation of In[727]:= discreteData::unknown: Result of applying function List to discreteData object is unknown

Out[727]= discreteData[1]
```

But

```
In[728]:= Hold@discreteData[1]

Out[728]= Hold[discreteData[1]]
```

And including Simon Wood's example now:

```
In[734]:= discreteData[1] + 1

During evaluation of In[734]:= discreteData::unknown: Result of applying function Plus to discreteData object is unknown

Out[734]= HoldComplete[1 + discreteData[1]]
```

Comment: You'll need to allow for multiple arguments, e.g. consider `discreteData[1] + 1`

Comment: Right, I'll toss that in. Although I think that should be a second case, because what the result should be there is less clear.

Answer (score 4):

You may continue to use `UpValues` and construct a pattern that raises a `Message` when a function not in the white list is called.

First create a `Message` to raise.

```
discreteData::undefsym = "discreteData not defined for `1`.";
```

`UpValue` pattern to raise the message when a non-white list function is used.

```
discreteData /:
 f_[___, d_discreteData, ___] /; 
  MemberQ[{Normal, Format, Length, Part, Set, If, List}, f] == False :=
 Message[discreteData::undefsym, f]
```

White list functions work as expected and others will not.

```
Sqrt /@ dd
```

> *discreteData::undefsym: discreteData not defined for Map.*

Note that this will work because `discreteData` is sufficiently deep in `Map` and defined for `Normal` when it is entered as a parameter to `Normal`.

```
Normal /@ {dd, dd}
Join[{dd}, {dd}]
```

This will not work and errors on `Sqrt` since  `discreteData` is not defined for `Sqrt` when it is entered as a parameter to `Sqrt`.

```
Sqrt /@ {dd, dd}
Join[dd, dd]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe you can shorten `MemberQ[{Normal, Format, Length, Part, Set, If, List}, f] == False` to `FreeQ[{Normal, Format, Length, Part, Set, If, List}, f]`